# Where has http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap gone?

Tags: xml, apache, soap

Where  http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap gone?

Thanks

Comment: Where are the Snowdens of yesteryear?

Comment: Based on [the way back machine](http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap), I'd **guess** "Nowhere as it never existed".

Comment: Based on a Google search which turned up [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-soapmap1/) it looks like `http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap` is a namespace, not a URL.

Answer (score 5):

`http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap` is a [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).  Its purpose is not to exist as a website (although it might do), but to uniquely identify elements and attributes in an XML document.

Comment: Do you know where one could obtain the xsd for this namespace?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of this before, but let's see what we can find.

First up, [the way back machine](http://wayback.archive.org/web/%2a/http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap) suggests that there has never been a document at the URL.

Let's try a a Google search which turned up [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-soapmap1/). Here that string of characters appears as [a namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/). Namespaces aren't URLs, they just look like them to help provide a globally unique identifier.

While there is a convention to store a schema or some other form of documentation at the URL which is identical to the namespace, there is no requirement to do so.

So we can conclude that it hasn't gone anywhere. There never was a document there. It is *just* a namespace.